# Singleton pattern in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, singleton

I have the following singleton

```
class WebSocketSingleton {

   IOWebSocketChannel _channel;

   WebSocketSingleton._privateConstructor();

   static final WebSocketSingleton _instance = WebSocketSingleton._privateConstructor();

   static WebSocketSingleton get instance => _instance;

   IOWebSocketChannel get channel{
   if(_channel == null){
      debugPrint("Creating new channel");
      _channel =  IOWebSocketChannel.connect(
         "wss://42zn68xb57.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/Test");
    }

    return _channel;
   }
}
```

Every time I call `WebSocketSingleton.instance` it created a new instance of `IOWebSocketChannel`.

Questions:

Shouldn't the `WebSocketSingleton` return a previously created instance of the `IOWebSocketChannel` instead of creating a new one every time I call `WebSocketSingleton.instance`?

Answer (score 0):

I think there is some issue in your `IOWebSocketChannel.connect` which is not able to create an instance.

Here is the similar code like yours except I am using default constructor when creating a new instance and "creating new channel" is printed only once.

```
class Channel {}

class Singleton {
  Singleton._();

  static final Singleton _instance = Singleton._();

  static Singleton get instance => _instance;

  Channel _channel;

  Channel get channel {
    if (_channel == null) {
      print("Creating new channel");
      _channel = Channel();
    }

    return _channel;
  }
}


void main() {
  Singleton.instance.channel;
  Singleton.instance.channel;
}
```

Comment: ok, thanks for that. 
The connect is from the flutter web_socket_channel package (https://pub.dev/packages/web_socket_channel)

Answer (score 0):

I think there is some issue with a connecting method which I guess it's static, I am calling connect by creating object of the class, and it's working as the only a single instance is created.

```
void main() {
  WebSocketSingleton.instance.channel;
  WebSocketSingleton.instance.channel;
  WebSocketSingleton.instance.channel;
}



class WebSocketSingleton {

  IOWebSocketChannel _channel;

  WebSocketSingleton._privateConstructor();

  static final WebSocketSingleton _instance = WebSocketSingleton._privateConstructor();

  static WebSocketSingleton get instance => _instance;

  IOWebSocketChannel get channel{
    if(_channel == null){
      debugPrint("Creating new channel");
      _channel =  IOWebSocketChannel().connect(
          "wss://42zn68xb57.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/Test");
    }

    return _channel;
  }
}

class IOWebSocketChannel {
  IOWebSocketChannel connect(String url) {
    return this;
  }
}
```

Comment: ok, thanks for that. 
The connect is from the flutter web_socket_channel package (https://pub.dev/packages/web_socket_channel)

Comment: Haven't tried it yet, will give it a try when I get to work tomorrow!